# makefile - alway recompile version.c when recompiling other c files

Tags: makefile

I want to recompile `version.c` whenever an other c-file has changed. So i tried to touch the c-file whenever an other c-file has changed. The Problem is that make doesn't recognize the change when it is allready doing the c-compiling. I think the reason is that it has already updated all dependencies. Is there a way to break the chains?

For example:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTFILES) $(TARGET).a

$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o: %.c | $(OBJECTDIR)
  $(if $(filter $(VERSION_BUILD),0),$(shell touch $(PROJECT_ROOT_PFAD)/$(VERSION_FILE)))

  #When VERSION_FILE then VERSION_BUILD is set to 1
  $(CC).....
```

So i want make to recognize the updated file immediately.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? What does `version.c` contain?

Comment: infos about the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to recompile version.c whenever an other c-file has changed.

So, you must declare that the result of the compilation of `version.c` depends on the other C source files. The following computes the list of the other C source files and assigns it to a make variable:

```
OTHER_C_SOURCES := $(filter-out version.c,$(wildcard *.c))
```

The result of the compilation of `version.c` is `version.o`. The rule you need is thus:

```
version.o: version.c $(OTHER_C_SOURCES)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

That's it. It says: if `version.c` or any of the other source files change, rebuild `version.o` by executing:

```
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS)  version.c -o version.o
```

(`$<` expands as the first pre-requisite - `version.c` - and `$@` as the target - `version.o`).

Note: the solution you are using is very far from the normal make strategy. You should probably reconsider all this and base your Makefile on the classical `target: pre-requisites` dependency graph.

Comment: Yes, i don't like my solution. You got the correct solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The youltion was to add `version.c` at the very last to `OBJECTFILES` because it all depends of the order.

```
fileA.c
version.c
fileB.c
```

If touched `version.c` when it compiles `fileA.c` then `version.c` was recompile but not when `version.c` was touch when `fileB.c` was compiled because version.c was allready checked. So the solution is:

```
fileA.c
fileB.c
...
version.c
```